# HTML5 Canvas mask out specific color

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

We had a company create a flash style image find kind of app using jpgs as the image layer and a png layer with.  The png layer was just an invisible image with specific hex values that sat above the art layer.  When the user rolled over an area, flash would find the HEX value of that location on the png layer and find the correlating label from an array that was set up with all of the HEX values and their labels.  When the user clicks on the area flash fills a transparent white rectangle around the entire image accepts for all of the areas in the HEX value.  So flash is able to create the mask from just a HEX value.

I am tasked to re-create this in HTML5, I have everything working accept for the part where the user clicks, and everything gets masked out.

I created a base art div that holds the actual artwork, then I created a canvas element above the art div that holds the png layer.  The canvas elements opacity is set to 0, and I have a mousemove function that picks up the imageData from the png layer, converts it to a HEX value to display the correct label from our database.  Though, I am stumped on how to use the HEX value from the png layer to create a mask when the user clicks on the area.

Also, our CEO doesn't want to take the time to re-do any of these image files because we have hundreds of them.  So I am stuck with the jpgs and pngs.

Any help would be great, even an idea of where to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's an outline of how to use a color-mask-png to display only the mask pixels in another image:**

- Create a display canvas with the .jpg image
- Create a non-visible canvas with the .png mask
- Listen for mousedown events
- In mousedown, get the mouse position
- Fetch the mask color at the mouse position (using getImageData)
- Get all pixels on the display canvas
- Iterate the mask canvas imageData and make all corresponding display canvas pixels transparent except for the selected mask color.
- Apply a label based on the selected mask color

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/szPQf/

**Illustration of .jpg and .png canvases before clicking:**

[image]

**Illustration of .jpg canvas after clicking (Only blue mask pixels visible + label)**

[image]

**Example code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var maskCanvas=document.getElementById("maskCanvas");
    var maskCtx=maskCanvas.getContext("2d");


    var maskImgData;
    var selectionDone=false;

    var loadedCount=0;
    //
    var flags=new Image();
    flags.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    flags.onload=start;
    flags.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/flags1.jpg";
    //
    var mask=new Image();
    mask.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    mask.onload=start;
    mask.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/flags1.png";
    //
    function start(){
        if(++loadedCount<2){return;}
        canvas.width=flags.width;
        canvas.height=flags.height;
        ctx.drawImage(flags,0,0);

        maskCanvas.width=mask.width;
        maskCanvas.height=mask.height;
        maskCtx.drawImage(mask,0,0);

        maskImgData=maskCtx.getImageData(0,0,maskCanvas.width,maskCanvas.height).data;


    }


    function getMaskColor(x,y){
        var p=maskCtx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data;
        return({r:p[0],g:p[1],b:p[2],a:p[3]});
    }


    function applyMask(pixel){

        // get the pixels on the display canvas
        var canvasImgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        var data=canvasImgData.data;

        // make all pixels on the display canvas transparent
        // except for pixels matching the selected mask
        for(var i=0;i<maskImgData.length;i+=4){
            var isInMask=(
              maskImgData[i+0]==pixel.r &&
              maskImgData[i+1]==pixel.g &&
              maskImgData[i+2]==pixel.b &&
              maskImgData[i+3]>15
            );
            data[i+3]=(isInMask)?255:0;
        }
        // put the masked image back to the display canvas
        ctx.putImageData(canvasImgData,0,0);
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){

        // exit if the user has already made their selection
        if(selectionDone){return;}
        e.preventDefault();

        // get the mousedown position
        mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

        // Put your mousemove stuff here
        var pixel=getMaskColor(mouseX,mouseY);

        // exit when no mask pixel was clicked
        if(!(pixel.r+pixel.g+pixel.b)){return;}

        // user selected a mask area, set the selectonDone flag
        selectionDone=true;

        // make all pixels in the display canvas transparent
        // except for pixels matching the selected mask
        applyMask(pixel);

        // label
        if(pixel.r>0){label("Red Mask area.");}
        if(pixel.b>0){label("Blue Mask area.");}

    }


    function label(text){
        ctx.fillText("You clicked in the",130,50);
        ctx.fillText(text,130,65);
    }


    // listen for mousedown events
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Click on a Flag</h2>
    <h4>Display canvas</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
    <h4>Mask canvas</h4>
    <canvas id="maskCanvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is basically the idea I was trying, but couldn't get all the pieces to work.